# Image Captioning with Attention results redundant caption

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, caption

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqkrf.png

My sample image caption from several times of training looks fine so far, except generating repeated phrases in a sentence.

It is using checkpoint 6 where the epoch resumes from. There are 6000 captions randomly chosen from a full set.

I assume the reason can be that there are the same captions selected or checkpoint repeats some kind of training result.

Any ideas or advice are welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Are using `SOS` and `EOS` tokens?

Comment: what model do you use?

Comment: Yes. SOS = <start>,  EOS = <end> and caption comes between them. FYI, oov_token = <unk> and I also use <pad>. Is there any difference when not using them? @Vitrioil

Comment: I use inception V3 for image vectorisation. Also CNN and RNN for image process and text (caption) process. @Ha Bom

Comment: Okay, can you provide more information? Like how are you training, and provide sample `x_train`, `y_train`?

Comment: It will be easy to understand when you see the code https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/image_captioning. It's an official tensorflow website. My train caption data set is 'train_captions' and its matching image set is 'img_name_vector'. num_examples is 60000 instead of 30000 which is a default value. @Vitrioil